# Traduire des phrases vues dans Capretz

Tags: traduction

> Un dessert sans fromage est une
> belle à qui il manque un œil. —Brillat-Savarin

et

> Un repas sans fromage est une belle qui n'a qu'un œil. - Tante Georgette

Traduction s'il vous  plaît, au sens propre et au sens figuré (en anglais).

Comment: Copie ta phrase ici https://www.deepl.com/translator en remplaçant **c**eil par **o**eil .  *o+e → **œ*** caractère typographique français

Answer (score 2):

> Un dessert sans fromage est une belle a qui il manque un œil.

A dessert without cheese is a beautiful woman missing an eye.

> Un repas sans fromage est une belle qui n'a qu'un œil.

A meal without cheese is a beautiful woman who has only one eye.

The meaning of both sentence is a metaphor to express that a meal where you go straight from the main course to the dessert without first serving cheese would be the equivalent of a beautiful lady missing an eye: almost perfect yet conspicuously missing something fundamental.